# Laravel Issue of Call to undefined function Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\openssl_get_privatekey()

Tags: php, laravel

I have one project in laravel which I fetched from the git repository. Now that project has  passport authentication added to the project. Now My concern is that, I have fetched from git repository and configure to my local wampserver but I can't able to access the project as I am facing the  following issue.
error message:

> Call to undefined function
>   Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\openssl_get_privatekey()

Comment: did you run composer install?

Comment: @CalinBlaga Yes,  run composer install command and it is successfully executed

Comment: is there such a function?

Comment: @CalinBlaga No. There isn't any function

Comment: That is a php native function( openssl_get_privatekey ). Why is trying to call it from namespace? Or maybe you need to enable open SSL?

Comment: Have you enabled the openssl module for php?

Comment: @CalinBlaga I tried to  enable openssl on my local system, but fail to do so. And one more thing, it is working fine on live server. My Live server isn't configured with SSL. So  I am not able to get what exactly the issue is.